# developing applications for windows mobile,c#

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

i work on visual studio 2008,now i want to create applications for windows mobile in c#.

what r d requirements and how to build them???

Do i need any kind of simulators

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Answering your question with right degree of detailing that it deserves
>   is beyond the scope here. So I
>   recommend you to [start from
>   here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx)!**

**[Windows Mobile Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsmobile/default.aspx)**

Answer (score 1):

There is a Windows Mobile SDK available for free from Microsoft, however you must use a full version of Visual Studio (not an Express edition).

Comment: windows mobile sdk 5.0 is already installed on my systen but how 2 use it or run application on it....
kindly help!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can now use Visual Studio 2010 express mobile edition as well.  This is nice because it seems to be the only one that is actually one stop shopping: no dumb SDK's, no extra vs project template plug-ins, etc...  Everything you need is in that one free DL.  Unfortunately WinMo7 is radically different from the previous versions so backwards compatibility will be be difficult.  The new environment is built on top of WPF tho which is nice to work with.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows Mobile SDK includes a simulator, but it is always sensible to debug/test on a device before release. This is really smooth using Visual Studio 2008 and USB connection to the device.

The .NET compact framework is a subset of the .NET framework. MSDN is good for telling you what's missing.

Comment: While it is generally desirable to have a real device for testing, I found that it is not really that important, especially if you are coding Windows Mobile Standard apps. The emulator was quite sufficient in my case.