# How to start developing for Samsung Omnia II

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-mobile, sdk

How should i start to develop for omnia 2? I have poor knowledge in c# and asp.net.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check out some of the other questions that explain how to get started developing for windows mobile, eg [developing applications for windows mobile,c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2116830/)

If you want to develop apps that run on the phone (rather than in it's web browser) you don't need to know about asp.net.